# Why does Sqlalchemy fail to insert big amounts of data to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I recently migrated from SQLite to MySQL and started suffering from this type of problem. Whenever I try using pandas' to_sql via sqlalchemy with more than 100 000 rows, sqlalchemy crashes with following message. I never had such a problem with SQLite (which I used without sqlalchemy). I have neither any problems copying these tables in PyCharm's SQL tool. But whenever I use the combination of pd.to_sql, sqlalchemy and mysql, I get into trouble.

Example code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

table = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000000, 10))
connection = create_engine(f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{user}:{pw}@{host}/{db}")
table.to_sql('TEST', connection, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Error message

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError) 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at '<host>', system error: 32 Broken pipe[<mySQLQuery>]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

This happens regardless if I use my local mysql database or the one I have in the cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common reason for this error is that the server timed out and closed the connection. This could happen for large datasets. Try using a `chunksize`:

```
table.to_sql('TEST', connection, chunksize=1000, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try. Do you know why this happens with Sqlalchemy and mysql as it never happened with Sqlite even with millions of rows?

Comment: You were right - it helped. Thank you, I have got plenty of grey hair, and also built myself several loops to avoid this problem. :)

Comment: @MattiH re: "it never happened with Sqlite" - SQLite doesn't use a database server; the client application reads and writes the database file directly, so there's no server connection to timeout.